# Winapi как правильно скрыть/показать окно сторонней программы?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, windows-10

Мне нужно скрыть/показать окно сторонней программы. Ищу окно с помощью `EnumWindows` и передаю в функцию:

```c
void show_hide(HWND window)
{
    if (IsWindowVisible(window) == TRUE) {
        ShowWindow(window, SW_HIDE);
    }
    else {
        ShowWindow(window, SW_SHOW);
    }

}
```

Все работает нормально, но только при условии, что окно скрывается/показывается через эту функцию или не скрыто. Если же скрыть окно руками, окно будет показано, но контент внутри окна не активный, пока не кликнешь по иконке в трее. 
Пробую на  Windows 10.

Edit:

Полный листинг:

```c
#include <windows.h>

void show_hide(HWND window)
{
    if (IsWindowVisible(window) == TRUE) {
        ShowWindow(window, SW_HIDE);
    } else {
        ShowWindow(window, SW_SHOW);
        SetForegroundWindow(window);
    }
}

BOOL CALLBACK enum_windows_cb(HWND window, const LPARAM lParam)
{
    const char* target = "Discord";

    char title[255];

    if (GetWindowText(window, title, sizeof(title))) {

        if (strcmpi(title, target) == 0) {
            show_hide(window);
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
    return TRUE;    
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    EnumWindows(&enum_windows_cb, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Еще записал видео с работой программы:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P-_Fi-Dew1w

Comment: Попробуй добавить `SetForegroundWindow(window);` сразу после `ShowWindow(window, SW_SHOW);`

Comment: SetForegroundWindow не помогает

Comment: Из вопроса непонятно, искомое окно свернуто в трей и Вы пытаетесь его показать? Что значит *скрыть окно руками*?

Comment: Да свернуто в трей, скрыть руками - нажать на крестик например

Comment: Если окно свернуто, то можно попробовать уточнить его статус запросом `IsIconic` если `IsVisible` возвращает *ложь*. Если `IsIconic` вернет *истину*, то в этом случае выполняйте `ShowWindow(SW_RESTORE)`, которое восстановит окно в его прежнем (до минимизации) состоянии. В противном случае, Ваш прежний код должен работать без проблем.

Comment: Под свернутым в трей окном я подразумевал, что основное окно полностью скрыто и есть только иконка в трее, а для этого случая `IsIconic` всегда будет возвращать ложь. Дополнил свой вопрос видео и полным кодом, на котором такое поведение встречается

Comment: Отправьте сообщение SW_RESTORE

Comment: Посмотрел видео. Вполне возможно, что разработчики ввели некий флаг, который отвечает за внутреннюю прорисовку окна. Я нахожу это правдоподобным из-за того, что на видео Вы изменяете размеры окна, стало быть, оно активно (стиль WS_DISABLED отсутствует). При клике на иконку в трее внутренний флаг "сбрасывается" и прорисовка возобновляется. Вполне логично. Кстати, попробуйте Ваш код на любом другом приложении, которое сворачивает себя в трей. Если все будет работать как ожидается, значит с "дискордом" ничего внятного не получится.

Comment: Напоследок еще несколько "советов": можете использовать [UpdateWindow](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-updatewindow)(window), [RedrawWindow](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-redrawwindow)(window, 0, nil, RDW_INVALIDATE or RDW_ALLCHILDREN or RDW_UPDATENOW or RDW_FRAME). Еще один вариант - использовать `MicrosoftSpy++` чтобы узнать, какие сообщения шлет и какие результаты их обработки возвращает искомая программа.

Comment: @ヒミコ `SendMessage(window, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_RESTORE, 0);` - результат тот же. @Dima я попробовал на нескольких приложениях, везде результат такой же qBittorrent, OBS, так же на своих двух приложениях(одно на Qt, другое на Electron). `UpdateWindow` и `RedrawWindow `тоже без результата. Записал выхлоп Spy++ [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/YwGt88yh), записано три сообщения (клик по кнопке закрыть, клик по иконке в трее, и попытка использовать ShowWindow)

Comment: "Клик по кнопке закрыть" - кнопка находится в заголовке окна, верно? Если да, то весьма странно, почему не наблюдается отправки сообщения `WM_SYSCOMMAND`. Вероятнее всего разработчики кастомным образом обрабатывают нажатие по кнопкам в заголовке окна. Я также проделал небольшой тест и заметил, что при использовании `ShowWindow(SW_SHOW)` целевое окно получает сообщение `WM_ACTIVATEAPP`. В результатах работы `MicrosoftSpy++`, которые Вы привели (3-я часть) я такого сообщения не обнаружил вовсе. Следовательно, можно попробовать отправить его "вручную", задав все необходимые параметры.

Comment: для WM_ACTIVATEAPP нужен параметр dwThreadID - идентификатор потока, который владеет деактивизируемым окном. Что мне использовать? Я использовал такой вариант, но результат тот же: `SendMessage(window, WM_ACTIVATEAPP, TRUE, GetWindowThreadProcessId(window, 0));`

Comment: Если даже это не помогает, тогда увы, больше ничего посоветовать не могу. Возможно, проблема в самой ОС. Вы указали Вин10, а я на 7-ке проводил тест. В любом случае, Ваш исходный код (переведенный в Делфи) на 7-ке работает корректно как с "дельфийскими" программами, так и с программами на других языках (я про трей веду речь).